# Get value returned from Promise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I´m new to JavaScript and a little bit confused about `Promise`s, this is what I have:

```
export const testFunction = () => dispatch => {
    otherFunction().then(( response ) => {
        //do something...
        return response;
    }).catch(( error ) => {
        //do something...
        return error;
    });
}
```

In another file I'm trying to get the value returned from the `then` like this:

```
let result = this.props.testFunction()
```

And like this:

```
let result = this.props.testFunction ().then(( result ) => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(( error ) => {
  console.log(result); // undefined
});
```

But I get `undefined` as the `result`, what is the correct way of getting that value?

Comment: `testFunction` returns another `function`, not a `Promise`

Comment: `return otherFunction().then(...)`

Comment: Notice that .then takes a function parameter. This is where you are returning and is why it's not getting to the outer function's return value. Instead/to fix, just return the promise

Comment: Yet it returns `undefined`, my bet is he's missing the `return` on the second line. Also, if you want to catch the error at the end don't catch it in your `testFunction` or rethrow it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testFunction` is not returning a Promise so you can't use `then` or `catch` and returns `undefined` because well, it's not returning any thing.
Try to return a promise like the example below however I am not sure what the dispatch argument supposed to do so I have removed it and hopefully this'll help:

```
export const testFunction = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        otherFunction().then(( response ) => {
            //do something...
            resolve(response);
        }).catch(( error ) => {
            //do something...
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying to return a promise to use it in another file, you must use the following syntax:

```
const testFunction = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (error) {
            return reject(error); // this is the value sent to .catch(error)
        }
        return resolve(valueToReturn); // this is the value sent to .then(result)
    });
}
```

This is how you create a promise to use where you want, if it has an error it will sent to catch block, otherwise you should see the console.log(result) value.

And in your external file you can use the syntax that you are using, try it in that way to see the console.log value.

Here is a link to see more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise